# The behavior of quadratic formula in the limit $a\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, quadratics

$$\lim\limits_{a\to0}\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$b$ and $c$ are constants. As $a$ approaches $0$, what does the formula approach?

Example:
$$\lim\limits_{a\to0}\frac{-5+\sqrt{5^2-4·0.001·3}}{2·0.001}\approx-0.6$$

Comment: Assuming $b > 0$, write the numerator as $b\bigl(\sqrt{1 - \frac{4ac}{b^2}} - 1\bigr)$ and use a Taylor approximation for $\sqrt{1-x}$.

Comment: If you like, we can think of complex roots.  Then there is no difficulty involving $b<0$.  For a quadratic, there are two roots (counting multiplicity).  When $a \to 0$, one of the roots goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
&= \lim_{a\to 0}\left(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\cdot\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\right)\\
&= \lim_{a\to 0}\frac{-b^2+(b^2-4ac)}{2a(b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac})}\\
&= \lim_{a\to 0}\frac{-2c}{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\\
&= \frac{-2c}{b+|b|}
\end{align*}$$
If $b>0$, then you get $-\dfrac cb$, the root of the linear equation hinted in another answer; but

if $b<0$, then the limit does not exist, because

- the larger one of the two quadratic roots becomes $+\infty$ when $a\to 0^+$;
- the smaller one of the two quadratic roots becomes $-\infty$ when $a\to 0^-$;

Comment: I think when $b < 0$ you still get the limit as $-c/b$, but not for the root $(-b + \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac})/2a$ but for the root $(-b - \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac})/2a$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think so, but that is a different limit.

Comment: ok then u have my +1

Answer (score 12):

HINT: What happens to the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ as $a\to0$?

Comment: ...right, got it... $$\frac{-c}{b}$$

Comment: @MarkusFjellheim Notice that the limit does not exist if $b<0$.

Comment: Except perhaps for special cases involving b  and c, this doesn't seem to really approach the linear solution as a approaches 0, see other answers.

Comment: See also:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395004/quadratic-equation-with-0-coefficients

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{b^2-2cx}$, then your expression is the definition of $f'(0)$.

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{a\to 0}\frac{f(2a)-f(0)}{2a}$$

We know that $f'(x)=(-2c)\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b^2-2cx}}=\frac{-c}{\sqrt{b^2-2cx}}$

---

**Edit:** Reading the accepted answer causes me to notice that $f(0)=|b|,$ not $f(0)=b.$ So this proof only works when $b>0.$

When $b<0,$ then $\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{f(2a)-|b|}{2a}$ still converges to $f'(0),$ but $$\frac{f(2a)-b}{2a}=\frac{f(2a)-f(0)}{2a}+\frac{b-|b|}{2a}=\frac{b}{a}$$
and $\lim_{a\to 0}\frac ba$ does not exist, so your limit does not exist in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b \neq 0$; let $c \in \mathbb{R}$; let $N(0)$ be a neighborhood of $0$; let $f: a \mapsto -b + \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}$ on $N(0)$; and let $g: a \mapsto 2a$ on $N(0)$. Then $g \neq 0$ on $N(0)$. Since 
$$
\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)} = (-4)\frac{(b^{2}-4ac)^{-1/2}/2}{2} = -(b^{2}-4ac)^{-1/2} \to \frac{-1}{|b|}
$$
as $a \to 0$,
we have
$f(a)/g(a) \to -1/|b|$ as $a \to 0$.